# .toggleClass of a targeted ID

Tags: jquery

Having issues with toggling a class on a targeted div. I have a set of boxes being displayed, each with a button inside. Clicking this button is supposed to reveal a second box within that box. However, each box has a unique ID and I need to show only the targeted one.

The issue is the log displays the targeted ID correctly, however the class is not being toggled. When inspecting on chrome I can manually add the .show class and it works just fine so I know it is not the CSS.

When I tested `.style.display = "inline-block";` in place of `.toggleClass("show");` the console now says the target is undefined.

I use `.toggleClass("show");` with many other parts of my page without issue.

What is wrong with my jQuery that it won't apply the class `.show` to the targeted ID?

Also: I know this can be achieved via CSS only, however I need more flex than that in the future.

PHP, HTML and CSS

```
<?php
    i=0;
    while(i<20){
    i+1;
?>

<div class="box">
  <a class="openButton" data-target="i">open hidden box</a>
  <div class="hiddenBottom" id="i">stuff</div>
</div>

<?php ;} ?>

<style>
    .box {
     display: inline-block;
    }

   .hiddenBottom {
     display: none;
   }

   .show {
    display: inline-block;
   }

</style>
```

Jquery

```
$(".openButton").on("click mouseover", function(){
    $($(this).data("target")).toggleClass("show");
    console.log($(this).data("target"));
});
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML; the PHP is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target an ID in jQuery, the syntax is:

```
$("#MyID")
```

In your example, `data-target` is a number without a preceding `#`, so if `i` is 19, your selector is:

```
//i = 19
//$(this).data("target") = "19"

$($(this).data("target")) // $("19")
```

The above example, `$("19")`, won't select anything because it doesn't have a `#`.

You'll need to prepend a `#` and concatenate if you're trying to select by ID, like so:

```
$("#" + $(this).data("target")) // $("#19")
```

Comment: Fun story, I tried: $("#".$(this).data("target")) like an idiot. Your "+" is the solution and fixed my issue. Thank you for stopping me from going insane.